# Browser zoom crashes my vertical navbar

Tags: html, css, navigation, menubar, zooming

I got a problem that's related to the built in browser zoom (ctrl + scroll).
Im about to build a site with a vertical navigation bar along the left side, which is pretty standard stuff... Everything looks fine with the listobjects seperated by a "border-bottom: 1px solid black". The listobjects are perfectly positioned down to the bottom of the parent-div.

This is until I start checking my page with the browser zoom. Then the border at the bottom of the last listobject "jumps" down a notch and gets placed below the parent-div... And if I continue zooming in the site jumps a little uncontrollably.

Does anyone have a solution to this? (Pasting my code below)

```css
* {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}

body {
 background-color: lightblue;
}

div#wrapper {
 width: 1300px;
 height: 600px;
 border: 1px solid black;
 margin: 20px auto 0px auto;
}

div#header {
 width: 100%;
 height: 100px;
 border-bottom: 1px solid black;
 background-image: url(".././bilder/headerBG.jpg");
}

div#header > h1 {
 color: white;
 padding-top: 15px;
 text-align: center;
 font-size: 55px;
 font-family: Algerian, "Times New Roman";
}

div#navbar {
 width: 300px;
 height: 500px;
 border-right: 1px solid black; 
}

div#navbar > ul {
 text-align: center;
}

div#navbar > ul > li {
 list-style-type: none;
 border-bottom: 1px solid black;
 font-size: 25px;
}
  
div#navbar > ul > li > a {
 color: black;
 text-decoration: none;
 display: block;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 width: 100%;
 padding: 35.5px 0;
}

div#content {
 width: 1000px;
 height: 500px;
 float: right;
}

div#footer {
 width: 1300px;
 height: 50px;
 margin: 0px auto;
 border-left: 1px solid black;
 border-bottom: 1px solid black;
 border-right: 1px solid black;
 clear: both;
}
```

```html
      <div id="wrapper">
   <div id="header">
    <h1>Hello DIV</h1>
   </div>
   <div id="navbar">
    <ul>
     <li><a href="#">Start</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Vision</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
   </div>
   <div id="content">
    
   </div>
  </div>
 
        <div id="footer">
    
  </div>
```

Comment: Using IE 9 it appears to be working normally, what browser are you using?

Comment: Im using chrome and the border on the last <li> jumps down just below #wrapper border...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi I just checked your Css and the problems are due to Height given to the following divs :

```
#wrapper & #navbar
```

There is a blank div called `#content` because of which you see a notch which goes down !! 
To avoid it remove height from `#content` too

Comment: I think that solved the problem mate. But then, if I don't specify a height on content, how do I get it equal to the height of the navbar (which is now specified by the padding of the <a> ?

Comment: I did not understand why are you zooming in-out the browser?? any specific reason??

Comment: Browser zoom can be related to screen resolution, right? So, Im zooming in and out to see if the site works as intended, means that the structure of the site is the same. 

But I think I got rid of the glitch now, but do you have any idea of how to make my #content equal in size as my #navbar when Im not specifying any height?